# Why are my ruffles not attaching to the skirt properly?

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image: The highlighted part is the outline of the bottom of the skirt that I converted into a curve]

Everytime I try to add a curve modifier to the plane it ends up looking like this. What do I do so that it lines up with the bottom of the skirt?

Comment: hello, hard to tell, we lack informations, maybe tell a bit more or even share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Heres the link: https://pasteall.org/blend/8d10a286a3244ceab4749d7acfca1311

Answer (score 1):

Both the curve's origin and the ruffles' origin must be at the same position, so select the curve, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected*, then select the ruffles and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Selection to Cursor* and it will work (*Selection to Cursor* may be buggy though, you need to retry sometimes).

If you want to be able to see the *Curve*'s effect while in Edit mode, activate the *Curve's On Cage* option. Also maybe put the *Subdivision Surface* modifier on the bottom of your stack:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This fixed the issue but for some reason the edit only shows in object mode and not edit. Why might this be happening?

Comment: The modifier has to be applied to the object to be "real"

Comment: or you can activate the On Cage option in the Curve modifier in order to see its effect in Edit mode. Btw maybe put the Subdivision Surface modifier on the bottom of the stack.